# Is there a natural topology on $\mathbb{C}(t)[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ with this property?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, topological-groups

Is there a good topology on $A=\mathbb{C}(t)[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ so that $A$ is a topological algebra with the following property:

*For any $N>0$ and a polynomial $F\in\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ there exists an open set $F\in U\subset A$ so that for each polynomial $$\widehat{F} = \sum_i \frac{f_i(t)}{g_i(t)}x_1^{d_{1}^{(i)}}\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n^{d_{n}^{(i)}}\in U$$ the product $\prod_i g_i$ doesn't have zeroes in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|\leq N\}$.*

**My guess.**

For each $f\in A$ it is possible to correspond function $f : \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ with spherical metric on $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ and the compact-open toplogy induced from $C(\mathbb{C}^{n+1},\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\})$ to $A$ is possibly a good topology.

Comment: What happens with $F=  t$, did you mean the $f_i/g_i$ have no poles instead of the $f_i,g_i$ have no zeros ?

Comment: Corrected the question.